# cant import photos with nautilus

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, shotwell

I was using shotwell to import photos, but I couldn't stand the way it forced me to use their event folder structure.  I have read that nautilus will allow you to import photos, but I am not presented with any options to import them.  It recognizes the pictures, but when I select open in the Ubuntu photo viewer it says it can't see anything.  However, when I go back to shotwell everything imports, it just doesn't give me the control I want.  Any ideas on how I can use nautilus to import my photos?  I basically just want the ability to bulk name and determine which folders in my pictures drive they go to.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "importing" with respect to nautilus? Are you talking about downloading photos from a camera to your harddrive? Anything else would just be moving the pics to another location.

As for the bulk renaming, you might achieve some limited tasks using bash (eg. with the `for ...; do ...; done` command).

Comment: Yes, I am referring to downloading pics from my camera to my harddrive.

Comment: Well, there might be no menu item called "import", but your camera should get mounted as an external drive, so that you can navigate to the desired pictures in nautilus and then drag&drop them (or the complete folder) to any place you like. Drag&drop performs a copying (instead of moving) operation if the source and destination are not on the same disk/partition.